# Order data by association-related properties in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Post` model and a `Review` model, with a one-to-many relationship between them. I'm trying to write controller code to sort the posts. One of the ways I'd like users to be able to sort the posts is by their aggregated ratings, which are currently calculated by a simple average of all `review.rating`s belonging to that post. For the simpler orderings, I can just do something like `Post.order(id: :asc)`, but because each post's average rating is not an explicit property in the database, the same approach doesn't work.

I'm now wondering if it's even a good idea to try to do it with SQL, which I'm not experienced in, and if I should just make a method in the Posts model to return an ordered list of all the Posts. Obviously I can't write code as well as the frameworks are written, so no doubt my method would be much less efficient.

What's the best approach here, assuming I will also want to add more sort methods later? A stitched-together solution just this once doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to create a SQL query that can aggregate the average reviews score dynamically and then order, but generally that won't be very performant. Sorting records is fastest when a database can use an index. And if you want to paginate your posts, a calculated order will have to calculate values for every entry in order to work out which elements to show – so if you display 10 records out of 10,000 that's a *lot* of wasted processing.

Instead, I would suggest adding a field – say, `:review_average`, to your `Post` record, and giving it an index. Add a method to calculate the review score in your post class:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, inverse_of: :post

  def update_review_average
    update review_average: reviews.average(:rating)
  end
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :reviews

  after_create :update_post
  after_destroy :update_post

  private

  def update_post
    post.update_review_average
  end
end
```

That way, your sorting can be achieved with `.order(review_average: :desc)` and it will be megafast.